What is this usage of あたり?
……意図は不明だ. ただ次の指示を迷わなかったあたり、彼は着実に「自身の目的」へと近づいているように思う.
"His intention are still unclear. He didn't hesitate when it comes to making his next move, so it seems like he's steady approaching his own objective"
I understand the sentence is saying although the character objective is unclear, the fact he didn't hesitate and steady move to the next phase make it look like he's getting close to his goal.
But what あたり mean here?

This question is similar to: Understanding あたりも. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
